# Creating Distinct using Linq in C# using 3 tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, distinct-values

I am using the below query to create new entry into Investment Table.
The Investment_Id did get created, but it created a new Id for each (AUMProductId + IdClient + ReportDate). Where Report Date is coming from AceBi. I just need distinct AUMProuctId + IdClient.
Where in code should I handle this ?

```
var query = (from AceBi in context.AceBiMonthlyDaos
                             join Inst in context.Instruments on AceBi.AumProductId equals Inst.AceId
                             join FinAcct in context.FinancialAccounts on AceBi.IdClient equals FinAcct.AceClientId
                             join Invst in context.Investments on new { instrumentId = Inst.Id, finAccountId = FinAcct.Id } equals new { instrumentId = Invst.InstrumentId, finAccountId = Invst.FinAcctId } into pair
                             from Invst in pair.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new { AceBi, Inst, FinAcct, Invst }).Distinct();
```

Comment: You either need to only select the columns you want the distinct values of, or if you need other columns then you need to do a group by and determine how to aggregate the other columns.

Comment: How would I do that in the above query ?